# Finding all maximal transitive closured subgraphs in given graph

Tags: graph, closures, subgraph

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

I have an directed graph G = (E,V) which has a low number of edges. Now I try to find all subgraphs in it which are transitive closured and maximal which means there should be no subgraph which ist part of another subgraph.

The first idea I had was to start at every Node doing a DFS and on every step look if all edges for the closure exists but the performance is horrible. So I wonder if there is any faster algorithm